# Trying to read columns from an excel data and compare it against table data in Redshift

Tags: excel, amazon-redshift

To start off, I don't have write access so I can't create tables in Redshift. Now that is out of the way, I am trying to read a column of SKUs data [900K rows] in Excel and compare it against SKU data in my redshift database.

Is there anyway to do this?

All the solutions I have tried to come across advises to load the data into Redshift or S3 and then compare but I don't have that option unfortunately.

So this is what it looks like

Excel Data in File name "Sales.xlsx" and Sheet1 and Column 'SKU'

```
A12345
B12345
C12354
D12321
```

Redshift Sales Table 'sales'

company.sales

```
SKU    |Sold
A12345 | Yes 
B12345 | Yes 
C12354 | Yes 
D12321 | No
```

Any way to compare data between these two sources?

Something like

```
select sheet1.sku,company.sales.sold 
from sales.sheet1 
  inner join company.sales on sheet1.sku = company.sales.sku
```

Comment: You will need to import the Excel sheet into an intermediate Table in your Redshift database

Comment: Are you asking if this can be done _in Redshift_ or are you looking for a way _outside of Redshift_ to combine these two sets of data?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with POWERBI Desktop software:
You'll have to create two connections, one to the redshify, other one to excel file.
than merge both queries

[image]